# Best practice for NSManagedObjectContext + thread + singleton

Tags: ios, core-data, optimization, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an app use core data with allot of relationShip, let say i have models A, B and C,
some operation must be in a separated thread, i create 2 singleton S1 and S2 (and the AppDelegate one having his Context):

- S1 manage A and B: it have a context and i merge data to the appDelegate one when saving.
- S2 manage B and C: it have a context and i merge data to the appDelegate one when saving.

  1. is this a good solution? because i have to manage with which context i have to create the managed Objects, and if i do it wrong there's no choice, the app will crash.
  2. i think that there's a risk to have different data between contexts ?

Comment: i normally have a contextfactory, and which creates and caches the contexts with some ttl for every thread that asks the factory for a context. and all background ops deal with the managed objects in such a way that there is no interop and i pass the ids around. Not sure if that is the best, but it works for me.

Comment: something like this https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext/NSManagedObjectContext%2BMagicalThreading.m

Comment: i don't know why i can't answer my question, any way, i finally adopt the simplest solution: create a class function where we create a model specifying the context: + (model*) createInContext:(NSManagedContext*)aContext.